# Batch update to replace special characters in SQL Studio Management

Tags: sql-server, replace, string-manipulation

I am trying to remove/correct some special characters in my database that show strange behaviour when exported.

Specifically `&` and the apostrophe `’`

I ran a query to find the values that contain the special characters, and while the query succeed at finding them, I still cannot replace/remove them with the second query UPDATE (nothing happens):

```
SELECT 
[Loc1],[IND_KEY]
FROM [Database].[dbo].[List]
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Loc1)LIKE'%[&]%';

UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[List]
SET  Loc1 = REPLACE(CAST(Loc1 as nVarchar(4000)), '[&]','and')
WHERE Loc1 LIKE '%[&]%';
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

---

What if I wanted to replace the apostrophe with the single quote (this last one doesn't cause issue when exported). e.g.

```
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[List] 
SET Loc1 = REPLACE(CAST(Loc1 as NVARCHAR(4000)), CHAR(39), '''')
WHERE Loc1 LIKE'Lake'''s%';
```

It doesn't seem to be working, would the single quote need to be referenced in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Do not enclose the literal in the REPLACE function in square brackets. The enclosures are not needed in the `LIKE` clause either since you are looking for a single character.

Try:

```
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[List] 
SET Loc1 = REPLACE(CAST(Loc1 as nvarchar(4000)), N'&', N'and') 
WHERE Loc1 LIKE N'%&%';`
```

Also, I don't see a need for the `CAST` here:

```
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[List] 
SET Loc1 = REPLACE(Loc1, N'&', N'and') 
WHERE Loc1 LIKE N'%&%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reference the individual characters you want to replace by character code instead, to ensure you're referencing the exact character. You can do so using the [`NCHAR()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nchar-transact-sql).

Here's what your `REPLACE()` function turns into as an example: `REPLACE(CAST(Loc1 as NVARCHAR(4000)), NCHAR(38), N'and')`

The decimal code for an ampersand is 38, and for an apostrophe you can use 39.